# Why my C++ program do not works after this point

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Nerdrvox skzbnakan gumar = ";
    double invmoney = 0;
    std::cin >> invmoney;
    std::cout << std::endl << "Nerdrvox skzbnakan gumar = " << invmoney;
    std::cout << std::endl << "Qani tarov = ";
    int years = 0;
    std::cin >> years;
    std::cout << std::endl << "Qani tarov = " << years;

    /*
     * After this point the cmd says press any key to continue, after pressinga key
     * cmd closes. However it is supposed to do this.
     */

    double summary = invmoney;

    int months = 12 * years;
    for (int i = months; i < 0; i--)
    {
        std::cout << "Month " << i - months << std::endl << "Invested money"
                << summary << std::endl;
        double percent = summary * 0.1;
        std::cout << "Add percent" << percent << std::endl;
        summary += percent;
        std::cout << "Sum for month " << i - months << "is " << summary;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can you please tell me why and how to fix it?

Comment: Use the debugger and trace the execution. It's doing what you've told it to.

Comment: You've told it to loop "while `i` is less than 0", but since `i` starts at `months`, which is presumably `>=0`, your program never does anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is because your for loop isn't executing.

```
for (int i = months; i<0; i--)
```

Needs to be

```
for (int i = months; i>0; i--)
```

---

The `for` has the following structure:

```
for (initialization; condition; increase) statement;
```

As long as the `condition` is true, the for loop will continue to execute.  In your original example, `i` was being set to `months` which, depending on your input, will greater than or equal to zero.  This would make the condition `i<0` false, which would skip the loop entirely.

Comment: you beat me by 15 s  or it has to be opposite :P

Answer (score 1):

It does what it is supposed to do

```
for (int i = months; i<0; i--)
```

if the value of months is positive the loop will not run

change it to

```
for (int i = months; i>0; i--)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop condition:

```
for (int i = months; i<0; i--)
```

Says that it will loop as long as i is less than zero, therefore it don't even run the first cycle because i is bigger or equal to zero (assuming the user enter a valid year).